# java.security.DigestException: Length must be at least 32 for SHA-256digests

Tags: java

jdk1.6 run exception;jdk1.7,jdk1.8 run ok

```
Key key = KeysFactory.getPublicKey(pubKey);

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");
cipher.init(1, key, new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", new MGF1ParameterSpec("SHA-256"), PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT));
while (inputLen - offSet > 0) {
  byte[] cache; if (inputLen - offSet > 117) {
    cache = cipher.doFinal(data, offSet, 117);
  } else {
    //jdk1.6 run exception;jdk1.7,jdk1.8 run ok
    cache = cipher.doFinal(data, offSet, inputLen - offSet);
  } 
  out.write(cache, 0, cache.length);
  i++;
  offSet = i * 117;
} 

target = Base64Util.encryptBASE64(out.toByteArray());
```

Length must be at least 32 for SHA-256digests
I try

```
byte[] data = new byte[32]
```

but not good